Jobs stuck in Pending , Horizon-Redis-Laravel
My Job kept stuck in pending after it is being dispatched , It neither transfers to fail or neither to done/completed. I am using Redis Connection with Horizon for Queue and trying to test at Staging environment. Strange thing is that no exception or error is thrown anywhere and the Logger is also completely empty. I am running job on very less amount of data.The jobs are being dispatched using chain but in my condition no they are simply being dispatched as its only one row of data. The same job ran on Local Server for small amount of data but it also did issue with large data similar to this issue but not exactly this issue.-MultiTenant setup (https://i.sstatic.net/7ocMavqe.png)(https://i.sstatic.net/3rajrAlD.png)
Only this Job Stucks , Other Jobs run normally.
I tried running a Job on very small amount of data expecting it would immediately be changed to completed and the row data would be added to my staging DB but the job stucked in pending status and neither turned to completed or failed even after a long period of time and what was a strange thing to me is that no error or issue has been thrown.

Did you find a solution for this?
